# What does 'right-to-left' mean when describing bouldering problems?

Tags: bouldering

I'm relatively new to the world of rock climbing, having been bouldering at a gym for a few months. I'm planning on checking out a natural bouldering area (that is, one made of real naturally occurring stone) nearby. This is my first exposure to climbing outdoors.

[Mountain Project](https://www.mountainproject.com/) and local printed guides sort problems in a way that I don't understand. They can be 'left-to-right' or 'right-to-left'. What does this mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The guidebook that I have for climbing lists different routes left-to-right meaning when you are standing in front of the crag looking at the routes they are described in order of what you see going left-to-right.

Comment: It is worth noting that when a guide book switches between right to left and left to right depending on the boulder, it usually is because of how you approach the boulder. If the approach leads you to the right side of the boulder, it makes sense to list them right to left.